# SCCM - Change account that is used to join computer to domain

Tags: sccm

Our task sequences began to fail and managed to track down the issue to an account being disabled in AD. It is evident that SCCM is using this account to process some of the steps in the task sequence.

Where would such an account be defined in SCCM?

Answer (score 0):

With a little more searching I found the answer myself to be under "Apply Network Settings" in the task sequence!